# Error while doing apt update or installing any software package (18.04.1-Ubuntu)

Tags: apt, updates

```
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 43.255.166.254 80]
Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 43.255.166.254 80]
Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 43.255.166.254 80]
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Reading package lists... Done         
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 43.255.166.254 80]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 43.255.166.254 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 43.255.166.254 80]
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score -1):

Check you firewall ufw or iptables verbose to check if the specific ip addresses are blocked or not.

use sudo ufw numbered
OR
sudo iptables -L

to check the status and then

make the apt changes

Comment: The cause here is most likely the repos used, and not a firewall issue.